# Can Django migrate sessions from the "cache" to "cached_db" engine?

Tags: django, django-sessions

I'm currently running a Django application with `SESSION_ENGINE` configured as `django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache`. I'd like to change this to `django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db` to gain persistence.

Can I make this change without destroying the existing sessions?

Answer (score 1):

The `cache` and `cached_db` session backends use a different key prefix to store the sessions in cache. If you just change the session engine, you will not be able to access the old sessions.

You could write a simple `SessionStore` that subclasses the `cached_db` session store and overrides `load()` and `exists()` to check the old key first.